# Qlik Sense RegEx

Tags: regex, qliksense

I try to find any information about Qlik Sense and RegEx.
The target is RegEx in load scripting for string data.

I know it was possible in QlikView by VBA Macros.
But it is not suitable for Qlik Sense.
Not intresting way with Extensions or Mushups for Qlik Sense.

Is it possible to use RegEx in Qlik Sense?
Maybe some one know how call JavaScript function?

BR,
Alexey Ryzhkov

Comment: It is really intresting who set "-1" because I want ask the answer for question. Dear voter. If you know answer - write it. If not - you point of view very special. Please leave your opinion with you.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems you can.

I found [this page](http://wiki.qvsource.com/Using-Regular-Expressions-In-QlikView.ashx). I'm not sure how advanced these regexes are, but it says it's "high-performance". You'd have to test if it supports anything more than "regular expressions".

> The Text Analytics & Sentiment Analysis Connector in version 1.5.2.7 of QVSource and later contains a new RegEx option which allows you to run high performace RegEx find and replace operations from your QlikView and Qlik Sense load scripts.

It gives the following code example:

```
Tickets:
load
* from
QVDs\ZenDesk_Tickets.qvd (qvd);

Params:
load
'RegEx' as api,
'((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)' as regEx,
ZenDesk_Ticket_id as rowKey,
ZenDesk_Ticket_description as text
resident Tickets;

store Params into params.txt (txt);

TextAnalyserV2_SimpleFind:
LOAD
    rowKey as ZenDesk_Ticket_id,
    Match as SimpleFind_Match,
    Index as SimpleFind_Index,
    Length as SimpleFind_Length
FROM
[http://localhost:5555/QVSource/TextAnalyserV2/?table=SimpleMatch&appID=&processParamsSync=PATH_TO_QVW_FILE_HERE\params.txt]
(qvx);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I mean Qlik Sense functions or way to use JavaScript functions in load script. Because if we check software stack we can see a lot of JS. From Angular framework to RequireJS and so on.

QVSource well known 3rd side software.
But it is diffirent way. It is out of core features.

Comment: @АлексейРыжков I'm not familiar with Qlik at all, but I can see if I can find anything else